# Mac OS X, python 3.8 install, Jupyter notebook kernel fail

Tags: python3, jupyter-notebook

I have been using jupyter notebook on my mac via python 3.7 with no issues.  Just upgraded to Python 3.8, now jupyter notebook launches but attempting to open any prior notebooks, get error that I need to "set kernel."  Obviously, no idea what that means.  Thus, I uninstalled python 3.8 in a failed attempt to revert back to Python 3.7 (which worked fine).  That failed.

How can I set the kernel in Jupyter notebook so that Python 3.7 will once again work with it so I can start using it again?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new environment to use Python version 3.7, run:

`conda create --name jupyterPy37 python=3.7`

What follows the `--name` flag can be anything. I have used a name that signifies what it stands for. You can change an environment’s Python version by using the package management commands nicely described in https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c/